# How to repel labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

If the labels in the example below were to be overlapping, how could we implement a repel option? Thanks!

```
means <- df %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarize(across(c(wt, mpg), mean))
ggplot(df)  +
  aes(x=wt, y=mpg, color=cyl, shape=cyl) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_point(size=4, data=means) + 
  geom_label(aes(label=cyl), color="black", data=means) -> fig
fig
```

If I add the `geom_label_repel()` from the `ggrepel package`

```
 fig + geom_label_repel()
```

I get the error:

```
geom_label_repel requires the gollowing missing aesthetics: label
```

Comment: Did you try to replace `geom_label(aes(label=cyl), color="black", data=means)` with `geom_label_repel(aes(label=cyl), color="black", data=means)` ?

Comment: That did it, thanks. If you write this to a separate answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to map `label` so that `geom_label_repel` "sees" it. It doesn't have direct view of the mapping from other geoms. Just itself and the top `ggplot` call. You thus have two options.

Directly within the function

```
geom_label_repel(mapping = aes(label = cyl))
```

or in the top `ggplot` call

```
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(label = cyl)) +
```

Note that you'll probably have to specify `data` as Vincent mentioned in the comment if you want to label the `means` points.